# ? on Outputting MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm still trying to output MySQL table to the screen with a border but having trouble as I am new to PHP. What I have so far is:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inventory_form';
$username="***";
$password="****";
$database="inventory_form";

try
    {
    $link=new PDO($dsn, $username,$password);
    echo 'Connection is established';
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    $error_message=$e->getMessage();
    echo "<h1>An error occurred: $error_message</h1>";
    }
$query="SELECT * from Inventory";
$result=$link->query($query);

echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b>";
?>

<table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr> 
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Equipment Borrowed</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Service Tag</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Date Borrowed</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
  print $row['FName'];
  print $row['LName'];
  print $row['Eqpmnt_Brwd'];
  print $row['Service_Tag'];
  print $row['Date_Taken'];  
  print "<br>\n"; 
}

?>
```

Which outputs this:

> Connection is established
>   Database Output
>   Alan*****amera2345662014-06-25
>   Roger ***Laptop6477722014-06-08
>   John ****5647772014-06-10
>   Jim WilliamsSenteo Bag #12014-06-18
>   Joseph ****Camera5654452014-06-15
>   Sheilah****Camera6654452014-06-10
>   Steven*****Camera6678752014-06-10
>   Name  Equipment Borrowed  Service Tag     Date Borrowed

Can someone help on how to incorporate html so I can format  the table into a simple bordered output. I've been reading and searching but can't find a cogent example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic what you need...

```
<?php
  while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['FName'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['LName'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Eqpmnt_Brwd'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Service_Tag'] .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Date_Taken'] .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
?>
```

And don't forget to add the closing tag `</table>` at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you much. One question so I understand.You can have html tags inside php code if they are surrounded by ''? What I was reading said you had to surround php code with <?php><?> but that wasn't working. If I want to add some styling how would I add that? Thanks....

Comment: You could just use `echo '<tr class="row">';` and add a CSS file containing this class and the CSS rules

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your desired output, you want something like

```
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch()) { 
  print "<tr>";
  print "<td>" . $row['FName'] . "</td>";
  print "<td>" . $row['LName'] . "</td>";
  print "<td>" . $row['Eqpmnt_Brwd'] . "</td>";
  print "<td>" . $row['Service_Tag'] . "</td>";
  print "<td>" . $row['Date_Taken'] . "</td>";
  print "</tr>"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch()): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?=$row['FName']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

in `<td></td>` write your rows like this